# sbt command to invoke same version of scala used to compile

Tags: bash, scala, sbt

I am using a bash script to compile and run Scala programs and test scripts. The compiling looks like this:

```
cd ~/$project
sbt package
if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit $?; fi
sbt test:package
if [ $? != 0 ]; then exit $?; fi
path="export Test / fullClasspath"
export CLASSPATH=`sbt --error 'set showSuccess := false' "$path"`
```

The run looks like this:

```
~/scala-2.13.4/bin/scala $project.test.$1 "${@:2}"
```

As you can see, the Scala version is hard-coded, but I would like to know the sbt command to invoke the same version that sbt used to compile.

Comment: The Scala version is derived from the `build.sbt` file in the root of your project. It should have a line: `version := 2.13.4`. Do you have such line in your `build.sbt`?

Comment: Or can you at least add your `build.sbt` file?

Comment: Why do you need to add the claspath to abr manually? Why not just using `sbt run`?

Comment: Yes, I have a line in build.sbt that specifies my scala version, but that does not help me to access a reference to the command needed to run it from a bash script.

Comment: "sbt run" does not do what I need done. I have many "main" test drivers in my test directory, and I need to be able to run them by name. I also tried test:run and test:runMain, but those don't work for my purposes either.

Comment: @RussP. what do you mean that you have many test mains? One should not have a main in a test, if you want to run a spec by name you can use `testOnly package.Class` and that is all.

Comment: I am not just doing conventional unit testing. Each of my tests requires careful analysis of plots and other data, sometimes for days or even weeks to get it right.

Comment: I tried testOnly, but it didn't work for my purpose. To use it, what do I need instead of "main" test drivers?

Comment: If your tests aren't unit test run by test suite, don't put them in `test` folder. Just create a separate module `tests` which can be run as normal application (but separate from the main application) with `tests/runMain my.non.standard.Test`.